# Padding does not work in iE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I would like to have space around the content, inside the border of the element.

http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_padding.asp

I have used cellpadding which is working pretty good in FF but not in IE. The version of IE that I am using is **7.0.5730.13**

I have tried a simple table

```
<table style="padding:100px" border="1">
    <tr><td>123</td></tr>
    <tr><td>456</td></tr>
    <tr><td>678</td></tr>
    <tr><td>kuz</td></tr>
</table>
```

But the output does not have space at all.. If I am using padding tag at `<td>.` It is working good.
As padding is not working in IE. I used an alternate method.

I have created two dummy rows; one on top, another on the bottom and dummy columns one on right another left and I styled them with padding. It is working. Please let me know if there is any better method to have space around the content.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795803/padding-table-with-css-doesnt-work-on-ie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_table.asp
Table padding is only implemented via a cell (td)

Answer (score 4):

IE does not support padding on a table.  I'm guessing you want to do this to have a space between the edge of the table and the content.

You can however have the same result by putting the table in a div (this is cross-browser).

```
<div style="padding:100px; border: solid black 1px">
  <table border="1" style="border: solid transparent 0px; width:100%">
        <tr><td>123</td></tr>
        <tr><td>456</td></tr>
        <tr><td> 678</td></tr>
        <tr><td>kzuk</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The div will mimic the table's outer border.

Edit:
This will only work if your table is at 100% width.  You can however, restrict the width of the div, but then you'd have to know how wide you want it to be.

```
<div style="padding:100px; border: solid black 1px; width:300px">
  <table border="1" style="border: solid transparent 0px; width:100%">
        <tr><td>123</td></tr>
        <tr><td>456</td></tr>
        <tr><td> 678</td></tr>
        <tr><td>kzuk</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanku for the reply..I tried this way but i am not able to control the padding on the right side of the table.<div style="padding:50px 100px 50px 100px; border: solid black 1px"> I have changed like this as well. But the space on the right side of table is more than 100px

Comment: I'm sorry, I somehow expected you wanted a full-width table... the div will take up the complete width of the parent, so this approach will only work if your table also has 100% width.

Comment: No need to be sorry:) Thanks for ur reply and the time spent on it.

Answer (score 2):

Check that your ie is not running on quircks mode, verify that you placed these lines on top of your html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

They will prevent ie from loading quircks mode

Remeber, if you apply a padding to the table, like

```
<table style="padding: 100px">
```

This will leave a space between the table and its content, if you want to make space between cells and their content, is like vikrash said, or you may use `cellpadding`

Comment: I tried this and works in ie 8!, dunno about 7, but I think it should

Comment: I would like to have a space between table and its contents. So i need to go for padding at the table level. I have placed the lines that you specified on the top of html, stll it is not giving any space in IE 7.

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like this:

```
<td style="padding: 10px">
```

CSS style 'Padding' should be applied to td not to table.

Answer (score 0):

how about using margin to replace padding

```
margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
```