# IE 8 table padding issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, html-table

I've created a table which has  the following code:

```
<table class="details resultTable">
<thead class="details">
<tr class="details">
<th class="details headerText">Heading 1</th>
<th class="details headerText">Heading 2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="imu-details-view">
<tr class="details">
<td class="details">Text 1</td>
<td class="details">Text 2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

here is the CSS for the table

```
resultTable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}
resultTable th {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #6678B1;
    padding: 10px 8px;
}
resultTable td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding: 6px 8px;
}
```

Now the issue I'm having is, in Firefox the table looks like so:

[image]

and then in IE 8/9 this is what it looks like:

[image]

can some one explain how I can make the IE table look like the Firefox one?

Comment: Do you use a CSS reset? Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset

Comment: Try This:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795803/padding-table-with-css-doesnt-work-on-ie

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. add align=left to  tag.

```
 <th align="left" class="details headerText">Heading 1</th>
 <th align="left" class="details headerText">Heading 2</th>
```