# Left-floated <li> padding not being seen in IE 8/9

Tags: internet-explorer, html-lists, padding

I've got a navbar on a site that's using floated LI's.  They all look great in every browser except for IE 8/9.  It seems these IE browsers are not recognizing the padding attribute for some reason (no matter what I set the value to, it doesn't reflect any change made to it).  But every other browser does.  Can't seem to find an answer in any of the existing questions I've looked at.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you provide maybe a link to the website or some code on how you are padding it? It might be that you are forgetting units or doing something that wouldn't be compatible with the IE browser. But without some code we cannot know exactly what it is.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response... here's the CSS:

#top-navigation li {
float: left;
list-style: none;
margin-right: 4px;
border-right: solid 1px #2C6A97;
padding: 0px 13px 0px 13px;}

Comment: Doctype is xhtml 1.0 transitional

Comment: Ok, well IE is always a problem.

Is it possibly 'float:left;'? Is there a way to achieve what you want without floating the list and does IE pad correctly when its not floating?

Comment: There's no way to get a list horizontally aligned without floating, no?  Or unless I make them inline blocks, but then IE7 doesn't recognize that.  I could use a table?  What's the standard procedure for a navbar?

Comment: I myself always use tables. But I believe what I found described below will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Though I do not actually own Internet Explorer 8 or 9. I understand the problems that arise when working with it. I did a little searching myself and found this article. Though it doesn't have to do with li but rather tables. I believe the same method will work.

[Padding table with CSS doesn't work on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795803/padding-table-with-css-doesnt-work-on-ie)

The method described is to wrap your code around a div tag and put padding on the div like so:

```
<div style="padding: 0px 13px 0px 13px;">
<li>Your normal list goes here</li>
</div>
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: This would mean I have to wrap every LI with a div tag though.... seems like there has to be a different way, otherwise what's the point of the LI?

Comment: Thanks for the help... but I ended up figuring it out by following http://woorkup.com/2010/08/09/best-practices-to-design-a-perfect-html-navigation-bar/ ... I'm not sure exactly what fixed it, but it's good now.  :)