# Table padding doesn't work in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

i have a table that consists of two rows, the second row is a table, which i want it's elements to be centered to the main table, so my code is as follows:

```
<TABLE>
  <TBODY>
    <TR>
     <TD>
      <DIV id=gform:scan_area>
        <OBJECT></OBJECT>
      </DIV>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
   <TD>
    <TABLE style="PADDING-LEFT: 300px"> // works in firefox but doesn't work in ie9
     <TBODY>
      <TR>
       <TD>
         <INPUT>
       </TD>
       <TD>
         <SPAN></SPAN>
       </TD>
        <TD>
        <INPUT>
        </TD>
      </TR>
     </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
   </TD>
   </TR>
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

**ISSUE:**  `TABLE style="PADDING-LEFT: 300px"` works fine in firefox but doesn't work in **IE9 (Quirks mode)**, please advise how to fix this issue or if you have any other ideas.

Comment: Any usable code on jsfiddle maybe? And the most important question of all: Quirks or standards mode? And which version of IE?

Comment: @Јοеу, IE9 quirks mode.

Comment: Then fix that first. There is no reason at all that a website should be in quirks mode. Ever.

Comment: try adding: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
`

Comment: Use border-spacing http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/border-spacing

Comment: Quirks mode is the problem. Get out of quirks mode, because it is designed specifically do do layout differently to a standard browser. You will never get cross-browser compatible code while you're using quirks mode. To get out of quirks mode, simply make sure that your [HTML code is fully valid](http://validator.w3.org/), and ensure it has a valid DOCTYPE at the start. (first line `<!DOCTYPE html>` should do the trick)

Comment: Also, please be aware that the table structure you've got there looks very much like bad code. Tables should not be used for page layout.

Comment: possible duplicate of [padding table with css doesn't work on IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795803/padding-table-with-css-doesnt-work-on-ie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is not written well enough, it was much better if you used "colspan" for solving this issue.
Any way, I tried to change your code in a way that centralize the second table in the first table:

```
<TABLE>
  <TBODY>
    <TR>
     <TD>
      <DIV id='gform:scan_area'>
        <OBJECT></OBJECT>
      </DIV>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
   <TD>
    <TABLE style="width:60%"> 
     <TBODY>
      <TR>
       <TD style="width:20%;padding-right:160px;">
         <INPUT>
       </TD>
       <TD style="width:20%">
         <SPAN></SPAN>
       </TD>
        <TD style="width:20%">
        <INPUT>
        </TD>
      </TR>
     </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
   </TD>
   </TR>
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: this solution worked for me but with adding padding-right to the first column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it this way

```
<div style="padding-left: 300px;">
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

For more read this answer: [Padding table with CSS doesn't work on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795803/padding-table-with-css-doesnt-work-on-ie/4796001#4796001)

Answer (score 0):

Table padding is only applied to cells. By adding it to the `<td>` you will see it work in IE9 and Firefox. See: [W3schools: Tables](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_table.asp)

```
<TABLE> // works in firefox but doesn't work in ie9
 <TBODY>
  <TR>
   <TD style="PADDING-LEFT: 300px">
     <INPUT>
   </TD>
   <TD >
     <SPAN></SPAN>
   </TD>
    <TD>
    <INPUT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
 </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```