# Center property seems 'shifted' and table mis-position

Tags: css, html-table

Being a customer service staff with limited access to basic html, I've been assigned a task that beyond my skill about making a decent page of highlight items, after series of search around, I somehow get things working, well, in firefox, when I load up the the same content in Chrome & IE, I found different problem and to my best effort, I have no idea what cause the problem...

You might first wish to look at the firefox version as it display perfectly as I wanted it to:
http://jsfiddle.net/kitchellw/TR6v5
(and I don't know why the first line doesn't apply the CSS...)

In IE, the round corner gone, which I won't worry too much... but

- padding is gone...
- the lower table looks like a mess
- I found a way to tackle the image border, just border=0

In chrome,

- while the upper section looks ok, the content in lower table seems 'shifted' to right by a few pixels and no longer stay center

Here is the exact code for the problem table at the lower section:

```
<table class=highlightitem>
<tr>
<td height="200" valign="top" >
<center>
<a href="http://www.digitalbuydirect.com/index.php?route=product/category&keyword=DSC-TX30" target="blank">
<img width=234 src="http://www.digitalbuydirect.com/edm/eDM20130516/TX30.png" /></a>
</center>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="200" valign="top" >
<font class=product><B>some text</b></font><br><br>
<font class=content>some text</font><br>
<br>
<font class=pricehighlight><B>price</font><BR>
<font class=content><s>other price</s></font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" height="50" valign="bottom" >
<a href="http://www.digitalbuydirect.com/index.php?route=product/category&keyword=DSC-TX30" target="blank"><img src="http://www.digitalbuydirect.com/edm/achieve/shopnow_35.png" /> </a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and finally, I know my code is complex by using multi-table to control the vertical  position, and CSS is my friend here, but i were unable to get the 'shop now' icon station at the lower right corner with clickable url attach with it, I found a CSS background image with a display block for the url might work, but the display block still request at least 1 character, which I cannot afford on my image. Any hint or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use center tags. They're deprecated in HTML 4.01 and not even supported in HTML 5. Use CSS to center the content instead. Also, the names of classes need quotation marks around them. If you made a JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem I'm sure I could fix it, but as it is right now I don't know exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: can i use, <div align="center">something</div> instead?

Comment: No, the div align property is the same way. Nowadays you should use CSS for almost all styling and formatting. All the HTML tags that did that stuff are deprecated or don't work anymore. For centering like this, I'm not sure, but `text-align:center;` might work

Comment: thanks for the head up, i would try that. could i also ask, is there any reason would prevent the 'padding:10px' from working in IE?

Comment: Not unless something else is overriding it, no. There are no compatibility issues with IE and the CSS padding property.

Comment: To center content on screen, set a width and set the left/right margins to `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should really clean up your deprecated code.

So far the things I've seen that are deprecated or not supported anymore are as follows:

`<center>` - Use CSS `text-align:center;` [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp)

`<font>` - Use another element like `<p>` coupled with [CSS text styling](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp)

`<td align="right">` - Use CSS `float:right;` [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_align.asp)

`<td valign="top">` - Use CSS `vertical-align:top;` [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp)

As for your IE padding problem, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617071/padding-does-not-work-in-ie). I'm not sure if that's applicable though, since you didn't include your CSS in the question, so I don't know how you implemented the padding you already have.

As for centering, using `margin:0 auto;` will work for statically positioned elements. For absolutely or fixed position elements I do this: `#elementID{width:800px[specify width]; left:-400px[negative half of the width]; margin-left:50%;}`

Comment: just like to make sure i am doing the right thing, i can use *<span>* to replace the *<font>* i am using... right? as *<p>* would open a new paragraph with space lying top & bottom of my text

Comment: thanks! things looking good, i guess i could kill off much of the issues, and i would read around about the padding for IE stuff ^^ cheers guys and thanks again!!